# Variable affectation or IF statement IE issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this (very) simple code:

```
var myvar = $('.selected').text();
if (myvar == "foo") { //do some stuff...}
```

It works in Firefox, not in IE_6. What's the problem?

Of course I `alert($('.selected').text())` which gives me the right value.

And I change the code to:

```
var myvar = "foo";
if (myvar == "foo") { //do some stuff...}
```

Then it works in IE.

any explanation?

Comment: Since you posted `...`, isn't `myvar` perhaps overwritten somewhere in between?

Answer (score 2):

you are selecting a set of elements which have `class="selected"` -- if there is more than one element in the list you might end up with a few spaces before/after the actual "foo" text. Have you verified that is not the case? 
Try changing to using `id=selected` if possible -- i.e. `$("#selected")` which should give you one element only.

Comment: you can see if you have any whitespaces quickly by changing your alert to: `alert("|" + $('.selected').text() + "|" )` -- and you should be able to spot it.

Comment: U fix it !!!!!!!!!! Thanks a lot !!!! I don't know where this 'space' is coming from...

Comment: @Zamboo thank you -- I don't think I've fixed it though, I think I've only revealed what the problem was ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that IE is giving you some whitespace that Firefox isn't (or vice-versa).  Try this:

```
var myvar = $('.selected').text().replace(/^\s*(.*\S)\s*$/, '$1');
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: @Pointy : there should be a probem with ur xpression  $('.selected').text().replace(/^\s*(.*)\s*$/, '$1') cause it doesn't remove space as expected, or I missed something ?

Comment: @Zamboo oops you're right - it'll have a problem with (some) trailing spaces. I'll edit it.  (It's only supposed to remove leading/trailing spaces, not all spaces.)

Comment: @Pointy jQuery.trim() perhaps?

Comment: @Lobo - well now that I notice the "jquery" tag on the question, that would certainly be a fine thing :-)  Thanks for noticing that.

Comment: @Pointy : myvar = $.trim(myvar);

Answer (score 0):

Is the code being called on page load? If so, have you wrapped it in a `$(document).ready()` function?

If not, it might be getting run while the DOM is still being constructed, and since IE is slower at building the DOM than Firefox, IE might not have built the `.selected` element by the time it runs this code, whereas Firefox could have.

I've seen a number of issues with JQuery that looked like cross-browser issues at first glance, but turned out to be just because of not using `$(document).ready()`.

The white-space suggestions in the other answers also sound plausible, though.

Comment: @ Spudley : Yes, my code is called on page load...I called it through $(window).load(...)